# Find left hand limit and right hand limit of $g(f(x))$ at $x = 0$ and hence find $\lim_{x\to0}g(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{x}{\sin x}, & x>0\\
    2-x, & x\le0
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
    x+3, &x<1\\
    x^2-2x-2, &1\le x<2\\
    x-5, & x\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

Find left hand limit and right hand limit of $g(f(x))$ at $x = 0$ and hence find 
$\lim_{x\to0}g(f(x))$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    5-x, &x\le0\\
    \dfrac{x}{\sin x}+3 &0<x<1\\
    \left(\dfrac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2-\dfrac{2x}{\sin x}-2, & 1\le x<2\\
    \dfrac{x}{\sin x}-5 &x\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

Let's find left hand limit

$$l=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}g(f(x))$$
$$l=\lim_{x\to0^{-}}5-x$$
$$l=5$$

Let's find right hand limit

$$r=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}g(f(x))$$
$$r=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{x}{\sin x}+3$$
$$r=4$$

$$l\ne r$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}g(f(x)) \text { doesn't exist }$$

But actual answer is following:

$$l=-3,r=-3,\lim_{x\to0}g(f(x))=-3$$

What mistake am I making here? I tried to find it but didn't get any breakthrough.

Answer (score 1):

We have that since $x>\sin x$ for $x\neq 0$

- as $x\to0^+, y=f(x)\to1^+ \implies \lim_{x\to0^+}
     g(f(x))=\lim_{y\to1^+} g(y)=-3$

and

- as $x\to0^-, y=f(x)\to2^+\implies \lim_{x\to0^-}
     g(f(x))=\lim_{y\to2^+} g(y)=-3$

therefore the limit exists.

Comment: what mistake I did in finding left and right hand limit?

Comment: @user3290550 You are composing the functions in a not proper way. Just rename $y=f(x)$ and consider $g(y)$. As $x\to 0^+$ we see that $y=f(x)\to 1^+$ and therefore we need to consider $\lim_{x\to 1^+} g(y)$. And similarly for the left side limit.

Comment: see what I did, I first composed g(f(x)) irrespective of limits and then I tried to find the left hand and right hand limit, what's wrong in it?

Comment: @user3290550 That's not an effective way for the calculation of the limit. For example let consider $g(y)=y+3$ as $y<1$. To compose we need that $y=f(x)<1$ which is true for $\pi+2n\pi<x<2\pi+2n\pi$. It is a complicated way to follow, if you are not requested you should avoid that,

Comment: ok going by your way, there is a small error in your solution, for $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$, $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sin x}$, so $g(x)$ would be $x^2-2x-2$ as $f(x)\rightarrow 1^{+}$ that would give $-3$

Comment: @user3290550 Opssss yes of course! I fix that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't compose the functions in the proper way, thanks to @user for pointing it out.

I found an interesting way to compose it which will avoid mistakes.

Replace $x$ by $f(x)$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    f(x)+3, &f(x)<1\\
    (f(x))^2-2f(x)-2, &1\le f(x)<2\\
    f(x)-5, & f(x)\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    f(x)+3, &\begin{cases}
   \dfrac{x}{\sin x}<1, &x>0\\
   2-x<1, &x\le0
\end{cases}\\
    (f(x))^2-2f(x)-2, &\begin{cases}
   1\le\dfrac{x}{\sin x}<2, &x>0\\
   1\le2-x<2, &x\le0
\end{cases}\\
    f(x)-5, & f(x)\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    f(x)+3, &\begin{cases}
   \dfrac{x}{\sin x}<1, &x>0 \text { contradiction }\\
   x>1, &x\le0 \text { contradiction }
\end{cases}\\
    (f(x))^2-2f(x)-2, &\begin{cases}
   x\in R \text { and } \dfrac{x-2\sin x}{x}<0 , &x>0\\
   x\le 1 \text { and } x>0, &x\le0 \text { contradiction }
\end{cases}\\
    f(x)-5, & f(x)\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    (f(x))^2-2f(x)-2, &\begin{cases}
   x\in R \cup x\in \left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right],&x>0 \text { rough estimation }\\ 
\end{cases}\\
    f(x)-5, & \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{x}{\sin x}\ge2, &x>0\\
   2-x\ge2, &x\le0
\end{cases}
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    (f(x))^2-2f(x)-2, &\begin{cases}
   x\in R \cup x\in \left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right],&x>0 \text { rough estimation }\\ 
\end{cases}\\
    f(x)-5, & \begin{cases}
    x\in \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2},\infty\right), &x>0 \text { rough estimation }\\
   x\le0, &x\le0
\end{cases}
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}
    \left(\dfrac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2-\dfrac{2x}{\sin x}-2, &x\in \left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right] \text { rough estimation }\\
    -3-x, & \text { otherwise }
  \end{cases}$$